# How does Excel obtain the R² determination coefficient in an exponetial regression?

Tags: regression, excel

How does Excel obtain the R² determination coefficient in an exponetial regression? This may seem a silly question but Excel actually shows a R² coefficient for non-linear regressions. How does Excel calculate it? Does it have any sense?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please bear in mind that excel does not handle missing values well. If your data column has some blank cells in it, if you filter them out, the r2 can change (subtly). Excel is fine for an overview but use a more robust method in case you want to get formal figures for publication.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer by myself. To make a exponential regression, excel takes the logarithm of the y values and applies a linear regression to it. Then, it reverses the operation.